# Wiring Baystat240a to Honeywell RTH2510 w/ picture

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I tried to hook up the wires but all the lettered terminals on my old thermostat don't match the letters on the Honeywell thermostat. I have the AC working but I still have three wires left over. I'm not sure what to do with them.
Also note the Baystat has 8 wires.[image: Apparently I'm only able to attach one picture.]

I know the Brown is not used. I don't know what to do with the black and blue wires.[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the wiring at the furnace/air-handler end?

Comment: Rather than asking new questions, you should use the Edit feature to add additional details to your questions.  I've combined all your questions into this one, so you can delete the other two.

Comment: Have you tried calling Honeywell? They run a support line for questions like this. We have heat pumps at work and they talked me through which wires to put where.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to base this on [this manual, page 8](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-2421ES.pdf), even though the diagram doesn't exactly match up in terms of order or number (terminal names and advice are the same). I suspect that this should work but **proceed with caution**. I would try calling Honeywell to verify this first

Based on the manual

- Blue - Wrap in electrical tape, do not use
- Brown - Wrap in electrical tape, do not use (T was not listed anywhere)
- Black - Put in the **W/Aux** terminal with the white wire that's already there

If I were you, I'd clip some of the bare wires back to minimize the chance that they short against each other. Also, be sure to set the jumper as outlined on Page 9

Comment: The manual says that if both W/Aux and X2 are present to put them in the same slot. Black is X2 here. If I'm reading something wrong please let me know